# angular customized validation - input parameter unchanged

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

There are two date inputs: d1 and d2.
The requirement is d2 must be greater than or equal to d1.

By default, the minimum date of d2 is 2018-09-03, which is stored in the **minDate** variable.

[A good case] If user inputs d1 first, 
it will trigger the function **onChange** and update **minDate** to the value of d1. In this case, if user wants to update d2, all dates before **minDate** are disabled.

[A bad case] If user inputs d2 first, 
and input d1 later with d1 > d2, I want the program to display an error msg by using the validation function **settledateValidator**.
However, **minDate** passed to **settledateValidator** is not updated (still equals to its default value 2018-09-03 instead of the value of d1).

My questions: 
1. why **minDate** does not get updated in [A bad case]? It is updated successfully in [A good case].
2. how to fix [A bad case]?

Thanks for your help in advance!

in .html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker_d1" placeholder="d1" [formControl]="d1" (dateChange)="onChange(d1)">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker_d1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker_d1 ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [min]="minDate" [matDatepicker]="picker_d2" placeholder="d2" [formControl]="d2">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker_d2" ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker_d2 > </mat-datepicker>
    <mat-hint *ngIf="!myform_fg.controls['d2'].valid"> d2 is smaller than d1 </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

in .ts:

```
function settledateValidator(min: Date): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {

    var sd = new Date(control.value);

    console.log(min);  //minDate does not change. it is still equal to its default value.

    if (sd < min){
      return {invalid_toosmall: true};
    }
  };
}

export class MyformComponent implements OnInit {

  minDate = new Date(2018, 8, 3);

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.myform_fg = fb.group({
      'd1': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'd2': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, settledateValidator(this.minDate)])],
    });

    this.d1 = this.myform_fg.controls['d1'];
    this.d2 = this.myform_fg.controls['d2'];

  }

  onChange(value: string): void {
    this.minDate = this.d1.value;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You validators in initialize in the constructor and you give the "this.minDate". When this one change you change is reference but the validator to still have the old one.

I faced the case and a way to do what you want to do would be to give the reference to an object which never change like this to your validator :

```
//global
const minDateValid = { date : new Date(2018, 8, 3)};

//constructor
settledateValidator(minDateValid);

//on change
this.minDateValid.date = this.d1.value;
```

---

For more exemple, I personnaly do it by passing the formControl for exemple : (see minDateFromControl) 
https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/validators/asi-validators.ts

and make it work like this :

```
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      from: [null],
      to: [null]
    });

    this.myForm.controls.from.setValidators([Validators.required,
    AsiValidators.maxDateFromControl(this.myForm.controls.to)]);
    this.myForm.controls.to.setValidators([Validators.required,
    AsiValidators.minDateFromControl(this.myForm.controls.from)]);
```